# Does anyone know why my execute immediate doesn't complie in PRO*C?

Tags: sql, c, oracle, embedded-sql

Can anyone figure out what is my mistake in the following PRO*C code? I cannot compile this:

```
int v1 = 5096;
int v2 = 8110;
int v3 = 8111;
int v4 = -1;
char stmt[6000];

strcpy(stmt, " MERGE INTO LDX_STYLE_MOVEMENTS ssd  USING (SELECT :1 pk from dual) ssd_pk   ON (ssd.style_movements_pk = ssd_pk.pk)  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN insert (style_movements_pk, style, from_subclass, to_subclass, reclassified_date, change_type_fk) values(LDX_STYLE_MOVEMENTS_SEQ.nextval , null, :2, :3, null, :4 )");   

EXEC SQL execute immediate  :stmt using :v1, :v2, :v3, :v4;
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: `EXEC SQL execute immediate  :stmt using :v1, :v2, :v3, :v4;` does not look like C to me.

Comment: This is PRO*C program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` ([dynamic SQL method 1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_13dyn.htm#i1962)) doesn't support the `USING` clause.

You can prepare and execute it instead (using [dynamic SQL method 2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_13dyn.htm#i2337)):

```
EXEC SQL PREPARE ora_stmt FROM :stmt;
EXEC SQL EXECUTE stmt USING :v1, :v2, :v3, :v4;
```

It doesn't look you really need to do this dynamically at all, but if you choose to do that then you need to use the appropriate method.

More details from the documentation:

> Method 1 parses, then immediately executes the SQL statement using the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command. The command is followed by a character string (host variable or literal) containing the SQL statement to be executed, which cannot be a query.
>
> The syntax of the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement follows:
>
> ```
> EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE { :host_string | string_literal };
> ```

...

> With Method 2, the SQL statement can contain placeholders for input host variables and indicator variables...
>
> The syntax of the PREPARE statement follows:
>
> ```
> EXEC SQL PREPARE statement_name 
>     FROM { :host_string | string_literal };
> ```
>
> PREPARE parses the SQL statement and gives it a name.
>
> The statement_name is an identifier used by the precompiler, not a host or program variable, and should not be declared in the Declare Section. It simply designates the PREPAREd statement you want to EXECUTE.
>
> The syntax of the EXECUTE statement is
>
> ```
> EXEC SQL EXECUTE statement_name [USING host_variable_list];
> ```
>
> where host_variable_list stands for the following syntax:
>
> ```
> :host_variable1[:indicator1] [, host_variable2[:indicator2], ...]
> ```
>
> EXECUTE executes the parsed SQL statement, using the values supplied for each input host variable.

Comment: Hi Alex!Thjis was just a simplified sample of my function. The actual function is really complicated and different arrays as inputs. I have to build this query dynamically. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Dax - it would still be helpful to future visitors to put the error you were getting into the question.

Comment: Good idea! :-) I'll do that